# Largest rectangle in 2d array

Tags: code-golf, geometry

## Input

The board: A 2D container (matrix, list of lists, etc.) of letters like:

```
  ["B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "B", "B", "C", "A", "A"],
  ["B", "A", "C", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A"],
  ["B", "C", "B", "C", "A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "B"],
  ["B", "B", "B", "A", "C", "B", "A", "C", "B", "A"],
  ["A", "A", "A", "C", "A", "C", "C", "B", "A", "C"],
  ["A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "C", "B", "C", "C", "C"],
  ["C", "B", "A", "A", "C", "B", "B", "C", "A", "A"]
```

If you choose a list of lists you may assume that all of the sublists are of the same length.

## Rules

- To make a valid rectangle you need all rectangle corners with the same 'letter'.
- Example, look the *sample board with* **X** bellow. You can see 'X' on (1,0) also on (4,0) also on ( 1,3) and on (4,3) then you have the rectange [1,0,4,3] that means from (1,0) to (4,3):

*Sample board with* **X**:

```
  ["B", "X", "C", "C", "X", "B", "B", "C", "A", "A"],
  ["B", "A", "C", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A"],
  ["B", "C", "B", "C", "A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "B"],
  ["B", "X", "B", "A", "X", "B", "A", "C", "B", "A"],
  ["A", "A", "A", "C", "A", "C", "C", "B", "A", "C"],
  ["A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "C", "B", "C", "C", "C"],
  ["C", "B", "A", "A", "C", "B", "B", "C", "A", "A"]
```

- The goal is to find the rectangle or one of the rectangles with the largest area, calculated by (right-left+1)*(bottom-top+1)
- If there are multiple rectangles with the same maximum area, output any one. Optionally the one with (top coordinate, left coordinate, right coordinate, bottom coordinate) lexicographically smallest.
- Rectangles must have edges parallel to the board's edge.
- Each letter is a printable ASCII char from A to Z (both included).

## Output

The output should be the left-up and right-down positions of the largest area rectangle corners. For the first sample "board" the big square is the yellow one:

[image]

And the answer should be:

> [1, 1, 8, 4]

#### A second example test case

An input of:

```
["C", "D", "D", "D", "A", "A"],
["B", "D", "C", "D", "A", "A"],
["B", "D", "D", "C", "A", "C"],
["B", "D", "B", "C", "A", "C"]
```

Should yield one of these three coordinate lists identifying an area six rectangles:

> [1, 0, 2, 2]
> [1, 0, 3, 1]
> [3, 2, 5, 3]

This question is posted on Stack Overflow with title: [How to find the largest rectangle in a 2D array formed by four identical corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49708412/how-to-find-the-largest-rectangle-in-a-2d-array-formed-by-four-identical-corners) and with this rude JS solution (I can say "rude" because is my code ;) :

Ok, is my first post, be tolerant with me please. I will change all you say to improve the quiz.

Comment: Hi, welcome to PPCG! This seems to be a good challenge, but seems to lack any winning criterion. Typically, posts here are tagged [code-golf], which means that the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Comment: I thought I would let you know that we have [a sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) that you can use to get feedback on questions before they are posted to the main site.  The sandbox is useful to pretty much everyone here but especially to beginners, who might not know all the rules and expectations we have.

Comment: @Arnauld, I ask for help to fix English but I guess the semantic was changed. Can you fix it?

Comment: May we use 1-indexing rather than 0 (so long as it is consistent)?

Comment: Some answers output the coordinates in sorting order for the "first" rectangle (i.e, top, left, bottom, right) instead of (left, top, right, bottom) as seen in your examples. Is this ok?

Comment: Less strict output formats usually encourage more answers, so something like `((left,top),(right,bottom))` should be fine too. I deleted my answer and answer again when the question is completely refined.

Comment: I'd suggest a test like `["A","A","B","C","D","E","F"],["G","H","I","J","K","L","G"],["A","A","M","N","O","P","Q"]` -> `[0,1,6,1]` (the two `G` making an area of seven vs the four `A` making an area of six)

Comment: So now each individual letter counts as a rectangle of area 1 if all else fails?

Comment: @Neil, yes. Looks more elegant like this.

Comment: @user56656, all answers are awesome, I've read ['What's the “accepted answer”?'](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8706) but I still have doubts. Can you explain to me which is usually the criteria to 'accept ans answer'? Are you so kind to help to me in this subject? 
I would like to avoid any injustice.

Comment: Sure, If you are going to accept an answer it should be the shortest overall, this is how most people like things done on the site.  However there is no consequence for not doing so.  There is also a [growing opinion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8363/56656) that accepting answers is detrimental to the site.  I am of that opinion, and thus I never accept answers on my challenges.  What you do is up to you.

Comment: Hi @user56656, thanks about explanation. I agree all your comment.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>148</s> 130 bytes

```python
lambda x,e=enumerate:min(((a-c)*(d-b),b,a,d,c)for a,y in e(x)for c,k in e(x)for b,g in e(y)for d,h in e(y)if g==h==k[b]==k[d])[1:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDLCoMwEEX3/YrBVVLGRbsUsrD5DJtFYuIDaxSxoF9vqdpiNO3mMgfmXIZpx75o7HXK2H16yFppCQMaZuyzNp3sTVSXlhAiw5SeiQ4VRYUSNaY0azqQOEJpwZBhxhSrLSrMFxxn1Fh8sMwgZ6xgrEqUeKcWNLlEYmq70vaQkSQJbgFCwD1x@8aM8RICTwCrFXt2Yw@6Fvf2Ouq6srV2lfw3rtaul7vTwd9ah/OPV3PH4n@F4w8FnV4)

Comment: Hi @ovs, is for you and inconvenient if I change the rule to figure up the area to: (x2-x1+1)×(y2-y1+1) as Angs did suggested?

Comment: I would like to relax some rules to encourage more answers. Can I?

Comment: @danihp Go ahead.This doesn't invalidate my answer, right?

Comment: Nop, your answer is right! Nice.

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>163</s> 162 bytes

```
Lw$`(?<=(.*\n)*((.)*))(?=(.))((.)*(?<=(.*))\4)((.*\n)*((?>(?<-3>.)*)(?=\4)(?>(?<-6>.)*))\4)?
$.7,$#1,$.2,-$.($5$#9*$5),$.2,$#1,$.7,$.($#1*_$#9*
4{N`
)m`^.*?,

0G`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYqxCsIwFEX3/EbekBfSYLRVBG1IE3ARv6BoHBwc7CCCgx8f32s6Xe455/34PKe7K@X8haz84aisHifUSlnUiMoToOG3WMSxZbBkvifebHrOqWZX0XZGHHsBdmdAOgN2bRqwCjqQew0dzqQaKkhIp2/sRPu7ZIGvfLXaGyFWp1xKTCmFIIYU66QYIs1A8wc) Edit: Saved 1 byte because the trailing `)` matching the `$.(` is implicit. Explanation:

```
Lw$`(?<=(.*\n)*((.)*))(?=(.))((.)*(?<=(.*))\4)((.*\n)*((?>(?<-3>.)*)(?=\4)(?>(?<-6>.)*))\4)?
```

This regular expression matches rectangles. The groups are as follows: 1) Top row (as capture count) 2) Left column (as length) 3) Balancing to ensure the left corners align 4) Letter for the corners 5) Width + 1 (as length) 6) Balancing to ensure the right corners align 7) Right column (as length) 8) unused 9) Height (as capture count). The `w` option ensures that all possible widths of rectangles are matched for each given top left corner. The `$` options lists the results using the following substitution pattern.

```
$.7,$#1,$.2,-$.($5$#9*$5),$.2,$#1,$.7,$.($#1*_$#9*
```

The substitutions are as follows: The right column, the top row, the left column, the negation of the area of the rectangle (literally calculated as the length of repeating the width string by one more than height number of times), the left column, the top row, the right column, followed by an expression that evaluates to the bottom row (a capture would have cost 12 bytes plus I've run out of single-digit variables). The first four captures represent the sort order in order of priority. As Retina sorts stably, a multicolumn sort can be established by sorting by each sort column in turn from least to greatest priority. (The area must be sorted in descending order, so a single string sort cannot be used.)

```
4{N`
```

Four numeric sorts are then performed.

```
)m`^.*?,
```

The sort column is then deleted after each sort.

```
0G`
```

The first entry is therefore now the desired result.

Note: The restriction on the choice of rectangle of a given area has since been relaxed and the following <s>144</s> 143-byte version prefers a wider rather than a taller rectangle:

```
Lw$`(?<=(.*\n)*((.)*))(?=(.))((.)*(?<=(.*))\4)((.*\n)*((?>(?<-3>.)*)(?=\4)(?>(?<-6>.)*))\4)?
-$.($5$#9*$5);$.2,$#1,$.7,$.($#1*_$#9*
N`
0G`
.*;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYpBCsIwEEX3c43MIhPSYNQqUm1IE3AjnqDQuHDhpgsRPH6csV09/nv//fy85oev9fbFosP5op0ZZzJaOzJEOrBgyFor0bgXsd5Cz77Z9XLnt7RFHf5KzgEadBpbVCeDLXXothaVt@iOVoLyZpIG9wKbawFnOqg15ZxjhCGnBTnFxBgYPw)

Comment: Fails the lexicographical-min requirement (try the test case I added to the OP for example) (maybe also output can be in the wrong order??) [TIO](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/36dcJUHD3sZWQ08rJk9TS0NDT1NLUxNIglkxJppwCXs7oDpdYzuQghgTKNcMzAXyuXRV9DRUlM21VEw1FVSUDRVU9IyA2EIBJGwEktDk8kvgMnBP4NKNSdHW4/r/39nFxcXRkcvJxRlCuTg7OgMpJyAFAA)

Comment: (...yeah first two values in output are the wrong way around I think)

Comment: I just relaxed some restrictions (lexicographical-min requirement ). I hope don't be a problem for you.

Comment: ...this will now need to match lines and points.

Comment: Fixing the lexicographical order cost 20 bytes :-( and I noticed that the area calculation changed, which cost another 2 bytes, but I don't know what @JonathanAllan means about points.

Comment: ...and now it's been relaxed to make the lex check unnecessary.

Comment: (by "points" I meant a single element would now be a 1x1 rectangle)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Ugh, in that case, I think I'd better delete my answer, since the regex required to match degenerate rectangles is going to be fiendishly complex.

Comment: Can you not just output `[0,0,0,0]` when nothing matched?

Comment: @JonathanAllan That doesn't help for the `1xw` and the `hx1` rectangles, but I've found a solution anyway, only cost another 20 bytes...

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), (27?)  <s>29</s>  28 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

<sup>27 if 1-based indexing is allowed - remove trailing `’`</sup>

```
Fṙ1s2;Uœị³EaZI‘P
ZLpLŒċÇÞṪF’
```

A full program.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/t4c6ZhsVG1qFHJz/c3X1os2tilOejhhkBXFE@BT5HJx3pPtx@eN7DnavcHjXM/P//f3S0kpOSjoKSMxbCCU6AuY4QIlaHSwGqyRGLUkcsXBRNzlhNRdEJVYKkCc1AZ9xciCY0U51RWRjakTRhOB3Tyc7ImpzxqscMvVgA)** (or see the other [test case](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/t4c6ZhsVG1qFHJz/c3X1os2tilOejhhkBXFE@BT5HJx3pPtx@eN7DnavcHjXM/P//f3S0krOSjoKSCyrhCCFidbgUopWc4MLOhBQgVDlCWOgKnDAUxAIA))

#### How?

```
Fṙ1s2;Uœị³EaZI‘P - Link 1, areaOrZero: list of pairs [[b,l],[t,r]]
F                - flatten the input                 [b,l,t,r]
 ṙ1              - rotate left one                   [l,t,r,b]
   s2            - split into twos                   [[l,t],[r,b]]
      U          - upend the input                   [[l,b],[r,t]]
     ;           - concatenate                       [[l,t],[r,b],[l,b],[r,t]]
         ³       - program's input
       œị        - multidimensional index into
          E      - all equal?                       X
            Z    - transpose the input              [[b,t],[l,r]]
           a     - logical AND (vectorises)         (if not X we now have [[0,0],[0,0]]
             I   - incremental differences          [t-b,r-l] (or [0,0] if not X)
              ‘  - increment (vectorises)           [t-b+1,r-l+1] (or [1,1] if not X)
               P - product                          area (or 1 if not X)

ZLpLŒċÇÞṪF’ - Main link: list of lists
Z           - transpose the input
 L          - length
   L        - length of the input
  p         - Cartesian product
    Œċ      - pairs with replacement
       Þ    - (stable) sort by:
      Ç     -   last link (1) as a monad
        Ṫ   - tail (note that the rightmost pre-sort represents the bottom-right 1x1
            -       so cannot be superseded by a non-matching rectangle)
         F  - flatten
          ’ - decrement (vectorises) (to get to 0-based indexing)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>83</s> 73 bytes

```perl6
{([X] (^$^a[0]X ^$a)xx 2).max:{[eq] $a[.[*;1];.[*;0]]and[*] 1 X-[Z-] $_}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZDLDoJADEX3fEVDiAECBFy4kLiA@hETm2ImUVbiAzcQ47cjiDK8optO79x7Os1cj/lpVWUlLFLYVA@TBIOZGIkknwUkhrSKApaWl8li/aDjjcGQ5JEdBhw2h88szweyGQIQLu3cOrB/Pqu7LCE1jb0F6SXXSCMddQf07bBEbWGn9uPuFv/4KhS13ciPJ77WJL4Z0dnYyXiG678bdZZKRjOyz@DszAH4iShGDMeNJPbkmxnNxGGHY1oxk7Wn@2KPwZ/x6b9pHFYv)

Returns a list of lists `((x0 y0) (x1 y1))`.

#### Explanation

```perl6
{
  ([X]                   # Cross product of corner pairs.
    (^$^a[0]             # Range of x coords.
     X                   # Cross product of coords.
     ^$a                 # Range of y coords.
    )xx 2                # Duplicate list.
  ).max:                 # Find maximum of all ((x0 y0) (x1 y1)) lists
  {                      # using the following filter.
    [eq]                 # All letters equal?
      $a[.[*;1];.[*;0]]  # Multidimensional subscript with y and x coord pairs.
    and                  # Stop if false.
    [*]                  # Multiply
      1 X-[Z-] $_        # for each axis 1 - (c0 - c1) == c1 - c0 + 1.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 121 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to @l4m2*
*-1 byte thanks to @tsh*
*+2 bytes to comply with the new rectangle scoring rule*

Takes input as a matrix of strings. Returns 0-indexed coordinates: **[x0, y0, x1, y1]**.

```javascript
a=>a.map(b=(r,y)=>r.map((v,x)=>a.map((R,Y)=>R.map((V,X)=>V+R[x]+r[X]!=v+v+v|(A=(x+~X)*(y+~Y))<b||(o=[x,y,X,Y],b=A)))))&&o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZFNasMwEIX3PoXrRRhF01wgUUCWT@BFsBFayGlSWpIoOMXYYHJ113V@ZamRYNBD73uMRt@60qd1@XX8eT@Yj023ZZ1mSz3b6yMUDEpsCFuWg4QKa3K7gxTzXqQXscKsFyuaylrRUmbqjVW03y1wBjU9Z2QKDT3nhCyKtgXDZI0NZpgrLBgnf2syMd3aHE5mt5ntzCdsQQZhKKM4wjASnhLfyyD5pSh8UNzj5R5pU8Kba6FXyzM1ihT/yys1yhX2yeGfKad9t2thUeIl4M4wUITMA99vDLbELp4ZJvfIl45k/HLHETuOobfuFw)

Comment: `a=>a.map(b=(r,y)=>r.map((v,x)=>a.map((R,Y)=>R.map((V,X)=>V+R[x]+r[X]!=v+v+v|(A=(X-x)*(Y-y))<=b||(o=[x,y,X,Y],b=A)))))&&o`

Comment: _If there are multiple rectangles with the same maximum area, output any one_; maybe `(A=...)<=b` -> `(A=...)<b`?

Comment: @tsh That's now safe indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 144 bytes

```hs
import Data.Array
o=assocs
f r=snd$maximum[((c-a+1)*(d-b+1),[a,b,c,d])|((a,b),x)<-o r,((c,d),y)<-o r,x==y,r!(a,d)==r!(c,b),x==r!(a,d),a<=c,b<=d]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7NasMwDMfveQqt9GBvyugug0F0sN23KD2occtM4yTYGSTQd8/kdMwY6//xA/mb8/3adesa4jikCY488btJiZdqIM55aHN1g0S59/vIc4g/8aRUW/Pbh35Vvr7IxBPjBVv0Z/1QSrTGWTf1AAkFRa9x@bMz0YLpRRiviUS0G7zJkiE3JFFD/rxmjmN3BYIu5Gn7ESh1wING9YWfWsPOyjHGOeOssdY5cVa0eFOi52u2onCClOv@20I7s6sih57GFPoJ9nCD5@L1Fw)

Comment: You can remove `b<=d`, as long as you keep `a<=c`.

Comment: @ovs actually that wont work either (see the example I added [TIO](https://tio.run/##LY5BC4JAFITv/oqXdNgXzxCim@@g7r@IDi/XaMlV2TVQ6L/bZl2GmY9hmIeEZ9t162rdOPgJtExyLL2XJRlYQhiakNzBc@jN3tneupe7KCVZgwdlshvSRehGDZkrviOnSGYssgE8KRUx0vKPM/NCfhc7BpmjabbyZr@MpOCICjbXNYgbuxYYOhum7Q0olVOOpE50RoS01lqXZaXrTXVd1pWuoqaJE9vz6G0/wR7u8JtaPw))

Comment: @nimi: I could argue that's just a matter of transposing the input.

Comment: It's ok for me. You can transposing the input.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 24 bytes

```
XLṭLp`€p/⁺œị€EɗÐfI‘PɗÞ0Ṫ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZC9TsMwFIX3PMWVGNpKQfw8AFISlx8pAyNVVQlTbhsX145iR1W3wtKBBYkBBsQDoDJDQWKpGHiM5EXCTSKCB/v4@pxP13eCUs6L4izM1q9hfJ7frOKd/Prj@z77vKVL9@dhczc6yRePp6Sed7P1S7FZ0kO2/qK9B9n7W754gpAbC1KoK2hvlh0XeBzLOZCDDyMXUoXk57IpTLRQcDEHhTMKIbR7naLowxZMU2lFLBEsEnDIDRqXXHgJHEZaW0zA6pq@jYRynH7L83y/5bj1OSDIPiQ4tFyNJRqYCRuB4VMEniB3XAoEjDHPKyM@CxrFAi@olV@qQWX1/ICVxe7h0XHFVvofXrNLLBzAXu2vVt3NX7YS3UqxhtN8VMdWTGk0RsvUCq0MmIgnQo3BRjQGTZ4RTUInChPHGfwC)

`⁺` proves to be useful.

Output format: *[top,bottom],[left,right]*. 1-indexing.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 38 bytes

```apl
a⊃⍨⊃⍒×/1+-/↑2 2∘⍴¨a←⍸≢¨↑∘.(∩¨)⍨∘.∩¨⍨↓⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU29CsIwEN7vKRwVqdW@QXJ5kVCpFAoVnJyFWsWIP4hODk5xd3BxqW9yL1Lv4qjhyPeT777YaRGN57YoJ1Fa2NksT1vanvKSqt0QqF5mraX1gpwP9@F9jkf9KKZqn3QSqi/kHo23HCb3pNWt8fzC9qBL9b3xPdljFYTw6sjlLde2GUhy8yJ3/R3QyEdrVAq0YqJ4mKI4igG0Fl8G2EGFIiDEUJYBAwsN8O8vQGOMdBr8guESBt7ADw)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>208</s> 205 bytes

```java
m->{int r=0,R[]={},i=m.length,j,y,z,u,t,T;for(;i-->0;)for(j=m[i].length;j-->0;)for(y=i*j;y-->0;)if((T=m[i][j])==m[u=y/j][z=y%j]&T==m[i][z]&T==m[u][j]&r<(t=(i-u)*(j-z))){r=t;R=new int[]{z,u,j,i};}return R;}
```

Can definitely be golfed.. I now use the most obvious approach of using <s>four</s> three nested for-loops.

-3 bytes thanks to *@ceilingcat* combining the inner loops of rows and columns into a single loop.

**Explanation:**

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##vZLBToQwEIbvPkVjomlNQe@1JlCuelj3QEI4VGS1FbqmFA1LePZ1Cqte7B5MlAxh6P9N6fyMlm8y0o8v@6qRXYdupTLjCULKuNpuZFWjO/86LxQlqnD1LG1RQtoSBsIEN0TnpFMVukMGcbRvo5sReGT5FV0VJR8nqngbN7V5cs9U04HuaE8dXbPN1mKmoujmihGfa94WqjyQTH8LA1cXmg3LgtpgvJ7JQpeEQ9bz4VKXxY4PZ7o8X/NF3B3S3nPn9ho7jlXUkwusox0hZLTcsRU39fvS3uiPpama2GRr11uDVmzas6XF1/6hgRYPnb5t1SNqwSx876wyT0UpyWLU/dC5uo23vYtfQXGNwRo8jnunmjixVg5d7LZLFTZxhf3nP11dtkDoNBVwpalIklOgBchzKSb0i0hATyDChPD1CTyCROp38REioF4kwjNBwh9B@POGCDEDP/QyAxP8CBZyLqz8wlORZdkRtzJxVM1E2IM0S0Pq/7WX50Lk3ub8T0cmT5P8z0cm/xyZ/NjITCfT/gM)

```java
m->{                         // Method with char-matrix parameter and int-array return-type
  int r=0,                   //  Largest area found, starting at 0
      R[]={},                //  Result coordinates, starting empty
      i=m.length,j,          //  x,y indices of the first corner
      y,z,                   //  x,y indices of the second corner
      u,t,T;                 //  Temp integers to reduce bytes
  for(;i-->0;)               //  Loop `i` over the rows
    for(j=m[i].length;j-->0;)//   Inner loop `j` over the columns
      for(y=i*j;y-->0;)      //    Inner loop over the rows and columns
        if((T=m[i][j])==m[u=y/j][z=y%j]
                             //      If the values at coordinates [i,j] and [y,z] are equal
           &T==m[i][z]       //      as well as the values at [i,j] and [i,z]
           &T==m[u][j]       //      as well as the values at [i,j] and [y,j]
           &r<(t=(i-u)*(j-z))){
                             //      And the current area is larger than the largest
          r=t;               //       Set `r` to this new largest area
          R=new int[]{z,u,j,i};}
                             //       And save the coordinates in `R`
  return R;}                 //  Return the largest rectangle coordinates `R`
```